# Run silent command on linux with perl

Tags: perl

Hi I'm trying to load in the background so you can tcpdump load silently, by that I mean to load but does not show anything

I had been told that using the command and put the end & would be achieved but the problem is it does not work.

The code is this:

```
#! usr/bin/perl
system ("tcpdump-s 0-A 'tcp dst port 80 and (tcp [((tcp [12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2): 4] = 0x504f5354)' & ");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to replace & with `> /dev/null`

Comment: Why are you even involving Perl?  Why isn't that a single line in a shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending `&` to the end of the string causes the shell to run the job in the background, but the job's output streams are still inherited from its parent.  Add some redirections to make the output go somewhere else.  For example: `tcpdump ... > /tmp/output &`  Since you are invoking `tcpdump` from `perl`, it seems more likely that instead of `system`  you want to open a channel and read from it: `open my $f, '-|', 'tcpdump ... (no trailing & or >)`

Comment: `popen`? I don't think there's such a function in perl.

Comment: Not even a `POSIX::popen` since `open` handles the work that `popen` would handle. But that's a minor detail; the rest is sound.